# Llamar una clase desde varias

Tags: java

Tengo una clase que llamada `LEEKs.java` en esa clase leo `Kh` con **`Kh = Viga.Kh`** y luego en la clase (viga) que llamó a `LEEKs.java` obtengo los valores `Ks`, `Kz`, `Kx` que son "`Double`" y ademas `Sigma` que es "`String`" con `Ks = LEEKs.Ks` y obtengo los demás con algo similar.

El problema es que yo quiero enviar `Kh` desde otras clases para obtener los valores de `Ks`, `Kz`, `Kx` y `Sigma` y no puedo usar **`Kh = Bases.Kh`** por que se superpondrian valores.

En definitiva tendría que llamar a `LEEKs` (enviando `Kh`) y obtener (`Ks`, `Kz`, `Kx`, `Sigma`) de vuelta.
Posiblemente tenga que usar un "*`Metodo`*" u otra cosa. desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido luisbisson. Si puedes añadir fragmentos de código de las clases, quizás será más fácil ayudarte a resolver este problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy completamente seguro de haber entendido lo que quieres, estaría bien que ampliases con fragmentos de código tu consulta. Según he entendido quieres enviar datos de una clase a otra (en este caso Kh) para devolver un valor diferente en función de la entrada). Para hacer eso las dos soluciones más comunes son estas.

**1. Constructores**

Para pasar ese valor a la clase debes crear un constructor.

```
String Kh = null;

public LEEKS(String Kh){
     this.Kh = Kh;
}
```

En este fragmento de código pasamos a la clase LEEKS el valor de Kh a través de la definición de la clase (es decir, instanciandola).

```
LEEKS leek1 = new LEEKS("aqui va el valor de KS");
```

Aquí tienes más información sobre el uso y definición de constructores:

http://www.mailxmail.com/curso-java/definicion-constructores-clase-1

**2. Setters**

Puedes utilizar setters para darle un valor a Kh en la clase LEEKS. Debes definir el setter así:

Declarariamos un metodo en la clase LEEKS

```
public void setKh(String Kh){
      this.Kh = Kh
}
```

Y sería tan facil como llamar a ese metodo con el valor deseado

```
setKh("valor de Kh");
```